# Recursively call different URL and wait for first site to be finished scraping using scrapy for Python

Tags: python, recursion, web-scraping, scrapy

I am wondering if there is a way to call more then one site recursively, to make  it more  dynamic. My instructor has asked to have scrapy crawl more than one website. This is what I have.

```
def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request("http://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g1009352-d1173080-Reviews-Yercaud_Rock_Perch_A_Sterling_Holidays_Resort-Yercaud_Tamil_Nadu.html", self.parse)
    yield scrapy.Request("http://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g297600-d8029162-Reviews-Daman_Casa_Tesoro-Daman_Daman_and_Diu.html", self.parse)
    yield scrapy.Request("http://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g304557-d2519662-Reviews-Darjeeling_Khushalaya_Sterling_Holidays_Resort-Darjeeling_West_Bengal.html", self.parse)
```

It works for the most part but it does it one by one, Is there a way to have it go through one site at a time not all at once. To sum it up, I need to to go through one yield at a time and then once that is done it goes to the next site and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this with the default configuration of Scrapy.

The main idea behind the tool is to make gathering information *fast*. And to achieve this it scrapes sites parallel. If you yield a `Request` it gets in the queue and as soon as a process or thread is ready it gets scraped. Then the result gets into another queue and then it will be scraped (the `parse` method or the defined `callback` is executed with the response).

To have one site scraped after another try to reduce the concurrent requests in the `settings.py` file to 1 with the `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1` setting.

You can read more about the settings in the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests).

Comment: Isnt there a priority http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.priority which can be set so that one is favored than the other and so on

Comment: If you have 16 parallel Requests the priority is very limited to give the expected results. If you run parallel working applications there is no guarantee on the execution order. You can eventually try to mix priority with the concurrent request amount -- but only the priority won't solve your problem.

Comment: Right now im looking into a while loop and then when that is finished it will kick up to the next ill see where it takes my program. Thanks for the help